# How to round with no trailing zeros in SQL Server 2005?

Tags: sql-server-2005, rounding

How to round with no trailing zeros in SQL Server 2005?

```
    select round(100.5555, 2)
```

...yields 100.55**00**. How to get rid of the zeros?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try this

```
select CAST(round(100.5555, 2) AS DECIMAL(8,2))
```

Comment: What if I don't know the lenght 8, the only thing I know is that I need 2 digits arter dot?

Comment: @astander: I got it, 8 is maximum, so I can just put any large enough number. Thanks!

Comment: You can't give a column inside the DECIMAL(8,xxx)  function

Answer (score 8):

You could re-cast it as your original datatype, e.g.

```
SELECT CAST(ROUND(100.5555, 2) AS FLOAT)
```

However, this sounds like display logic and therefore, I suspect you are better off doing this within your UI rather than your DB.

Comment: Needed this version as my query was specifying the ROUND based on SI units, and varied row by row, as @NicolasThery stated - you can't pass in a column to the DECIMAL function, but you can to the ROUND one.

Comment: @NicolasThery, it works on SQL Server, which is the tag of the question.

Comment: Personally I think MSSQL ought to be updated to provide a better way. You can argue that it's display logic, but sending a lot of unnecessary zeros increases the amount of data that needs to be passed between MSSQL and whatever is doing the display, so it seems like something that should be possible to control without an otherwise-unnecessary CAST operation. Just my $0.02.

Answer (score 1):

declare @d decimal(8,2) can help you.